# How can I detect when an annotation's UICalloutView is tapped?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView` with some pins with callout enabled. And it has a `rightCalloutAccessoryView` which is an `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`, which on tapped will open a detailView.

Now, I want the user to be able to tap anywhere on the callout view and open the detailView.

How do I detect that tap?

(Note that UICalloutView is a private api).

Answer (score 0):

When your left or right callout accessory view objects are subclasses of `UIControl` (which should be the case for you, as it sounds like you have a UIButton), the map view will automatically notify its delegate when the accessory views are touched. There is no need to manually set a target/action for your button.

Make sure your view controller or other appropriate object is set as the `delegate` of your map view. Implement the [`mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3aannotationView%3acalloutAccessoryControlTapped%3a) method. This method gives you both the annotation view and the specific accessory control that was tapped. You can check the `annotation` property of the annotation view object to get the data you need to display the detail view.